# Solve for integral limit

Tags: matlab, numeric, equation, numerical-integration

I need to find the limit of an integral in a numerical way, knowing the result of that integral. What I need to solve is:

[image: Integral equation to solve]

As you can see, that is the incomplete beta function. I know `a`, `b` and `c`. And the integral limits are from `0` to `x`. I need to find `x`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As you can see, this site doesn't support TeX/LaTeX. You can improve your question by replacing the coded formula with an image.

Answer (score 2):

The `fzero` function can solve all sorts of nonlinear equations.

First, calculate the incomplete beta function as a function of `X` (I subtracted the `c` because we want to find the `x` that makes `Y=0`):

```
Y=@(X) beta(a,b)*betainc(X,a,b)-c
```

or, without using the builtin `betainc` function, and instead using symbolic algebra:

```
syms t x
Y=matlabFunction(int(t^(a-1)*(1-t)^(b-1),t,0,x)-c);
```

Now use `fzero`, since `x` must be between 0 and 1, we constrain the solution to be within `[0 1]`:

```
x=fzero(Y,[0 1])
```

If `fzero` doesn't work, the simplest numerical method to try is a bisection search. It's easy, and works well here, so why not use it. I did assume that `Y(x)` is monotonically increasing on `[0 1]`, but I think that's always the case.

```
x=0.5;
xmin=0;
xMAX=1;
tol=1e-12;
numIts=0;
while abs(Y(x))>tol
    if Y(x)>0
        xMAX=x;
    elseif Y(x)<0
        xmin=x;
    end
    x=(xmin+xMAX)/2;
    numIts=numIts+1;
    if numIts>237 %// If it's not working, stop
        disp('Solution has not converged, there is probably no solution in [0,1]')
        break
    end
end
x
Y(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Actually I can't use betainc function, so I must do it following the definition of it. Will it be the same procedure?

Comment: See the edit. I think actually it should have been `beta(a,b)*betainc(X,a,b)` as well, looking at the definition of `betainc` in Matlab.

Comment: Hi, I have to thank you again, using beta and betainc the result is exactly what I expected (you were right about multiplying beta(a,b)). But using symbolic algebra gives me this error `>> matlabFunction(int(t^(v2/2-1)*(1-t)^(v1/2-1),t,0,x)-5);
Error using symengine>makeFhandle (line 109)
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.` I hope you can help me.

Comment: That's odd. Does it work if you just do the integration with `matlabFunction`?

Comment: I just checked again and tried with different values. For some values of a, b and c, it performs the operation and gives the expected result. But for others (the most, actually) it gives the error I mentioned or this one: `Error using fzero (line 242)
Function values at interval endpoints must be finite and real.` I guess some values make the integration more difficult. What could I do to avoid those errors? Thank you.

Comment: In those cases, I think you'd probably have to go to numerical methods. Can you give an example of an `a`, `b` and `c` that lead to these errors?

Comment: For example, c= 0.0157, b = 0.5, a=1.5, or the same c value with a=17/2, b= 9/2. I also think numerical methods are the answer to my problem, but I don't know where to start with that.

Comment: I've put in some code for the simplest numerical code imaginable, which works well here because the solution is in a fixed interval. It fails if there is no solution, I'll fix that up in a minute.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, the bisection search worked perfectly when fzero fails, and there were few cases where it didn't converge. Now I have another question: what can I do when the error is `Error using symengine>makeFhandle (line 109)
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.`, caused by the `matlabFunction` instruction? That's different because I can't use the `Y` for the bisection method.

Comment: I have no idea what could be causing that, what input values cause that?

Comment: For example, a =17/2, b=9/2, c=3.4080e-06. (I obtain these values doing operations before). Or a=500, b=0.5, c=7.9286e-04.